# Doctrine with always live data from database / clear is destroying everything / Ratchet chat

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entitymanager, symfony4

I'm developing a chat using Ratchet PHP WebSockets.
The problem is that I'm using Doctrine there for the database layer - and the script is not reloaded all the time like for normal web requests.

So I decided to use `$entityManager->clear()` on each connect. (OnMessage)
This works now the whole time except now when I want to persist new entities with normally new users.

**Use case:**

`onMessage`:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine */
$doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
$doctrine->getManager()->clear();

$user = $this->container->get(UserRepository::class)->find(1);
// checks for is enabled etc. works because user is always fresh from the database so
// if I disable him while the script is running it will be detected
```

Persist entity with data load fresh from database.

```
$user = $this->container->get(UserRepository::class)->find($subscriber->Session->get('user_id'));
if ($user) {
    /** @var \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine */
    $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
    $doctrine->getManager()->refresh($user);

    echo 'BEFORE ERROR' . PHP_EOL;
    $chatMessageStatus = new ChatMessageStatus();
    $chatMessageStatus->setUser($user);
    $chatMessageStatus->setChatMessage($message);
    $this->entityManager->persist($chatMessageStatus);
    echo 'AFTER ERROR' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Error:**

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\ChatMessageStatus#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: patrick. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

I'm using Symfony4 with Doctrine ORM 2.5.

Thank you in Advance for any ideas.

Comment: Why do you use `/** @var \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine */
    $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
    $doctrine->getManager()->refresh($user);` ? If you already have a $user defined variable. Where is your `flush()` method and have you tried using `cascade={"persist"}` in your ChatMessageStatus() entity?

Comment: As I understand your user entity should have OneToMany connection and setting $user with `->setUser($user)` there should also be somewhere `$user->addChatMessage($chatMessage)`.

Comment: The problem is that this user seems to be detached because it always says that the user should be persisted. The `refresh` is implemented to normally get fresh data from database so that it want not to persist them. But nothing works. Always this error. But I cant persist this user each time because it already exist :-( I must do it like this. But `clear` is not working as I want so this is my main problem.